# Angular UI Router: abstract : true won't display page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to wrap my brain around Angular UI Router with nested navigation.

My app has multiple pages. I've set up the StateProvider and the basic routing from page to page works. However, I am now trying to implement a tabbed view within one of these pages. I just can't get it to work.

A basic example can be seen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBLfD

Specifically: 1) the content of the first tab doesn't get loaded and 2) when I set abstract to false the page that holds the tabs does get loaded.

I've tried setting abstract to false, and then the page does load, but the contents of the first tab don't get loaded. I'm bashing my head on this- What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whichever tab you want to be the default, inherit from the abstract tab and set the url to

```
''
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gApoH

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. Been banging my head on this for way too long.

Comment: Some explanation:  your abstract route is at /tab but you can't go to /tab because it's abstract.  By inheriting from the abstract route and setting the url to nothing, the route remains at /tab, but you get all the goodness of the child route

Comment: Final question: because abstract is set to true, it won't register as a new history state. How can I set it so the history state does show?