# AngularJS 1.5 "Could not resolve '___' from state 'home'"

Tags: angularjs

I have looked at the other solutions. They basically state that you should be sure to include a call to the x.state.js file from the index.html file. I have that.

When I change the name of the state the error gets updated. So if I had a state called "mystate" and called it from a button's ui-sref it would say "Could not resolve 'mystate' from state 'home'. If I changed the ui-sref and the state name to "yourstate" the error message changes to "Could not resolve 'yourstate' from state 'home'. So I don't know where else to look.

Update with some code that I really just took from a website tutorial to test this out but here goes:
myupload.state.js

```
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
      .config(function ($stateProvider){
       $stateProvider
       .state('upload',{
        parent: 'home',
        url: 'upload',
        data: {
          roles: [],
          pageTitle: 'Upload Your Files',
          displayName: 'Upload Your Files'
           },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateURL: 'my/path/myupload/upload.html',
            controller: 'UploadController'
               }
        },
        resolve: {}
        })
   }
);
```

There is a upload.directive.js file in the same directory. A uploadcontroller.js file in that same directory. And a upload.html file.

In the 'home' page HTML file I have a button with the following syntax. When clicked it is supposed to route you to the above page for a file upload.

```
<button class='btn' ui-sref='upload()'>
```

There are no other errors to troubleshoot with.

I have a couple of other states to look at and this one looks just like those.

Those buttons/states work.

Where else should I be looking?

Comment: If you have added `State.js` file in your `index.html` problem must be something else. So You've to share some code snippet for figuring out the issue.

Comment: I've added the state file and the button that calls the page. Do you see anything?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but is your parent route set to abstract: true?

Comment: In app.js it does say "abstract:true", yes, for $stateProvider.state('site'. . . ). Is that where I find that?

Comment: I changed it to false and no change in behavior the page won't load. The other pages still load. Even found this which really didn't help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168222/angular-ui-router-abstract-true-wont-display-page

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be needed security code specific to the application I am working on (inherited) in the resolve: section of the state clause. Once I added that the button worked just fine.